# Syntax issue in tcsh alias

Tags: alias, tcsh

I have the following alias in a tcsh script

```
#!/bin/tcsh 

alias check_error 'set STAT="\!:1"                         \
echo "$STAT"                                               \
set FILA="\!:2"                                            \
echo "$FILA"                                               \
set DEST="\!:3"                                            \
echo "$DEST"                                               \
if ( $STAT != 1 ) then                                     \
   echo "ERROR: Failed  $FILA to $DEST."                   \
   exit 1                                                  \
endif'

set STATUS = 33
set fn = "2345"
check_error $STATUS $fn third
```

The first echo in the alias prints 33 as expected but it then fails with the message

```
0: Event not found.
```

I am not sure what the issue is

Comment: Using `set histchars` is the easiest way to disable `!` expansion; escaping that is always a pain.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but could you replace the alias with a separate script?